# Exception at insert to table - asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to do a simple registration page.

When I'm trying to insert some user to the table, I'm getting this exception:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll

This is my code:

```
    protected void reg_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try  
        {  
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["drone_connection"].ConnectionString);  
            conn.Open();
            string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO Users (Username, Password, Email, NAME, LAST_NAME, ADDRESS, Phone, Birth_date) VALUES (@1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8)";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", user_text.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", pass_text.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", email_text.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@4", name_text.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@5", lname_text.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@6", addr_text.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@7", phone_text.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@8", birth_text.Text);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  

            Response.Write("User registration successful!");  
            conn.Close();  
        }  
        catch (Exception ex)  
        {  
            Response.Write("error" + ex.ToString());  
        }

        Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
    }
}
```

I saw a lot questions about this exception, but still can't find the problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Exceptions come with messages, stack traces, inner exceptions, etc.  What are the details of the exception you're getting?

Comment: I notice that you are always inserting and that Username and Email are the primary key. If a record exists already with the Username and Email you're sending, then you are violating the primary key of that table. You need to provide more information about the exception to get a more detailed response.

Comment: You're also storing user passwords in plain text, which is a famously bad idea.  User passwords should be obscured behind a 1-way hash so they can never be read in their original form.  Not even by you as the system owner.

Comment: @Trioj, The table is empty now, so there is no problem with the key. it's not inserting at all.

Comment: I don't know where I can get more information. in the output, I saw only this exception. 
@David, I will do hash later. its only for learning.

Comment: @Maor.I: (1) The exception object itself has this information.  (The `ex` variable in your `catch` block.)  (2) When you're learning, that seems like the *ideal* time to, well, *learn*.

Comment: Please consider reading this and applying the knowledge therein: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: best that you look at your sql Insert statement and look at your column names you need to have the parameters match your column names please paste a more informative error message, learn to use the debugger

Comment: @David I know how to do hash, for now, I'm focusing on the insert.
This is a screenshot of the output maybe it will help: https://i.imgur.com/T51VrlM.png

Comment: @Maor.I: That's a screen shot of the database which was already included in the question.  So, no, repeating that doesn't add any new information.  What you want to do here is use your debugger, place a breakpoint inside your `catch` block, and examine the contents of the `ex` variable.  Or output its contents somewhere that you can observe.  The system is *literally telling you the problem*, you just need to observe what it's telling you.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is the link: https://i.imgur.com/UsSTlOP.png
I will try with the debugger again, but the question if you see any syntax mistakes?

Comment: @Maor.I: No, I see no obvious syntax mistakes.  Unless maybe you're mis-using a reserved word as an identifier in SQL?  But instead of *guessing* what you want to do is ***read the error message***.

Comment: I would start by using names for your parameters that make sense instead 1, 2, 3.... As for the issue at hand you have posted a screenshot which does not have the full line of information. You need to capture the actual error message which is almost certainly off to the right there in your screenshot where we can't see. Put in some break points and step through this.

Comment: I am going to guess that the SQL insert is failing at the last parameter ()you need to convert birth_text.Text to an sql date type

Comment: Posted my comment before I saw the answer. you should also look to modify your input from text to a datetime selector

Comment: @DaniDev the datetime was the problem, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@8", birth_text.Text);
```

You should [cast/convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-datetime) `birth_text.Text` into a date type.

Comment: That was the problem. thank you!!

Comment: That's great! If you are satisfied with the answer please [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks